# Show non members of a MKS sandbox

Tags: version-control, mks, mks-integrity

I try to get the non- members of a Sandbox. But I get these erorr message.

```
si viewnonmembers -sandbox=D:\Sandboxes\project.pj

*** MKS124814: Cannot show view information: MKS125335: Out of tree members and
subprojects (not located in the project directory or a subdirectory of the proje
ct directory) are not supported.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From help of `si viewnonmembers` you could use option `--cwd=value  Act as if command executed in specified directory` so the command should look like this:

```
si viewnonmembers --sandbox="D:\sandbox\test\project.pj" --cwd="D:\sandbox\test"
```

or with `--recurse` option to skip `Do you want to recurse into the directory...`

```
si viewnonmembers --sandbox="D:\sandbox\test\project.pj" --cwd="D:\sandbox\test" --recurse
```

Depending of your server configuration the `.pj` could be other than `project.pj`

Answer (score 0):

Non-members can only be viewed in a sandbox context, and not from any project view operation.

So, before executing the command, you should jump into your local sandbox location:

```
cd SandboxFolderPath
```

when you are in your sandbox folder, you can execute

```
si viewnonmembers
```